# Register/Trademark symbols in vertica

Tags: vertica

I have a txt file containing some data.

One of the columns contains Register/Trademark/Copyright symbol in it.

For eg,  "DataWeb @symphone ®" and "Copyright © technologies"

Now when I load this txt file in database, all data gets stored properly except these symbols ®©

Are they supported by vertica ? Are there any way to do this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertica supports Unicode characters encoded UTF-8. Your message is a little bit vague because is not clear what is your problem. If I were you I would double check those characters are properly encoded **and** your font set is able to visualise them. Here you have a little test...

**First** let's create a properly UTF-8 encoded file:

```
$ echo -e "DataWeb @symphone \xc2\xae" > /tmp/test.dat
$ echo -e "Copyright \xc2\xa9 technologies" >> /tmp/test.dat
$ cat /tmp/test.dat
DataWeb @symphone ®
Copyright © technologies
```

Then let's create/load a table:

```
$ vsql
SQL> CREATE TABLE public.test ( txt VARCHAR(20) ) ;
SQL> COPY public.test FROM '/tmp/test.dat' ABORT ON ERROR DIRECT;
```

And, finally, let's query this table:

```
$ vsql 
SQL> SELECT txt FROM public.test ;
         txt         
---------------------
 DataWeb @symphone ®
 Copyright © technol
(2 rows)
```

I'd suggest you to run this test from Linux using `vsql` command line interface (avoid Win and click-click interfaces).

Comment: Thanks for your reply !! I tried with UTF 8 encoded file and it worked..